# Mount command caused my homedir files to be updated in other location

Tags: linux, unix, mount, area

I have accidentally mounted some area on my homedir.

Here is the command: "sudo mount hgfs01n02a:/br_disks_seb_cer_def /nfs/br/home/username"

I should have done it differently and mount the desired area into a folder in my homedir. now what happened is that some of the files (such as .history , .Xauthority and more) are getting updated under /nfs/seb/cer/def and not under my homedir.

Any suggests what can I do to fix it? 
(I am using UNIX btw).

Answer (score 0):

Unmount the directory, and mount it in the right place ;)